# R - Combining column means in a matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix that looks like this and want to take the mean of each column and combine them into a new matrix.

```
> MDA
           price       X3        X5     X10      X13       X20      X64      X86
  [1,]  2.851921  0.19537  2.817065  6.5603  7.37657  2.273753  3.73926  4.08654
  [2,]  1.355820 -0.58857 -0.253762  4.3871  3.62105  5.070533  6.03979  3.90909
  [3,] -1.830597  1.74915  0.173217  5.5275  3.76552  3.100661  4.92384  3.16864
  [4,]  6.535637  4.59728  5.848335  6.8814 10.25615  6.663288  3.87881  8.71351
  [5,]  4.666041 -0.49024  2.353359  6.8693  8.86881  9.783803  5.42288  5.88306
  [6,]  4.959884  2.09005  2.677156 10.1798  7.68598  5.771700  3.64374  4.89176
  [7,]  4.014322  5.29507  0.238004  6.1883  6.52230  5.079508  5.33247  5.73703
  ...
```

To do this I've been using the following method (note all of this is done in a loop hence the `[x+1]`):

```
MeanMDA[x+1,] <- c(mean(MDA[,1]),mean(MDA[,2]),mean(MDA[,3]),mean(MDA[,4]),mean(MDA[,5]),
                 mean(MDA[,6]),mean(MDA[,7]),mean(MDA[,8]))
```

While this works perfectly, it gets really cumbersome when the number of columns gets large. Sometimes there's over 100 variables and I'll have to go through and edit the code accordingly... Is there another neater way of getting the code to take the mean of each row and combine it into a matrix?

Comment: We can use `colMeans` i.e. `colMeans(MDA)`

Comment: Normally it is not a good idea to put aggregated values (e.g. means) in the same matrix as the original values. Beside this you can use `rbind(MDA, ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `colMeans`

```
colMeans(MDA)
```